# Inserting into table values found from previous query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have table, let's say `'ROLEE'`., which contain columns **ROLE, ACCESSENTRY**.  I need to find first rows that **ACCESSENTRY** is equal to 'A' and for these rows insert into that table new rows with fetched '**ROLE**' and given **ACCESSENTRY**.
So let's say within this query:

```
select role from ROLEE where ACCESSENTRY='A'
```

I get 2 rows with values: ADMIN, USER
and for these roles (ADMIN, USER) I need to insert

```
INSERT INTO ROLEE
values ('ADMIN', 'ACCESS')
INSERT INTO ROLEE
    values ('USER', 'ACCESS')
```

I tried with these, but it does not work:

```
INSERT INTO ROLEE
values (role, 'ACCESS') where role in (
select role from ROLEE where ACCESSENTRY='A')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below insert statement,

```
insert into ROLEE (select role, 'ACCESS' from ROLEE where ACCESSENTRY='A');
```

The right way is to specify the column names,

```
insert into ROLEE(column1, column2) (select role, 'ACCESS' from ROLEE where ACCESSENTRY='A'); -- Provide the respective column names in colum1 and column2
```